# Can pytest receive regular python parameters or read params from configuration file?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to use pytest to test certain AWS Lambdas.

In order to perform certain things, I have to pass in some ID.

I've done it in very hacky way, having this in conftest.py:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    store = ParamsStore()
    try:
        parames = sys.argv[1:]
        print(parames)
        store.my_id = parames[1]
        store.dont_store = parames[3]
    except:
        store.existing_stack = ''
    parser.addoption("--myid", action="store", default="", help="Pass RunId To reuse it Later")
    parser.addoption("--dontstore", action="store", default=False, help="Pass True if you'd like to persist when tests are passing")
```

I understand it's "against" the pytest logic, but I need these parameters to be stored as a global params.

Now there are two problems I'm trying to solve.

1. I'd like it not to be hacky as is, where I'm intercepting params by reading arguments.

I've read all the "make fixtures" documentation and suggestion, but I need these to be used here, in conftest.py, before any tests. It's not even "before all" or per "each test" it's practically setting up the whole thing by reading local AWS cdk.out and manipulating cloud assembly (only once) before running tests, and that process is done once, so "per each test" is not needed.

The only way I see it so far, is to have two separate scripts, one regular python code, that is then run before pytest itself, but that becomes pain to handle, so I'm trying to bundle it and do everything just by using pytest.

If I can read args - it would work. If I can read some config file - it would work. If I can bundle pytest to "first execute some python prescript" then run pytest - it might work as well.

2. I'd like (and I'm not sure if 1 can be resolved better) to just pass a flag "--dontstore" without any value afterwards, and just the presence of the flag would imply something is 'True', while if it's not there it would be 'False'.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**
How about something like this in `conftest.py`:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--myid", action="store", default="", help="Pass RunId To reuse it Later")
    parser.addoption("--dontstore", action="store", default=False, help="Pass True if you'd like to persist when tests are passing")

def pytest_configure(config):
    my_id = config.getoption("--myid")
    dont_store = config.getoption("--dontstore")
```

Use these two variables for your setup.

**Option 2**

Set-up a jenkins job with the python script for the setup to be run before the pytests.

Comment: Thank you, for the Option 1 - I think "request" in pytest_configure will not work, as it's not there, I used just "config.getoption("--myid")" and that seems working, in a proper non hacky way. Or at least nicer than what I was doing earlier.

I don't understand the "default" parameter since it does nothing and it requires argument to be passed, but ok :)

Comment: `default`  defines what the test would use if nothing is passed for that parameter. If only you would need to pass something else, you would use that parameter with the value to be passed. I edited the code to remove the `request` part to make it correct.